# Where is my 'Wallet' app (ios8.4)

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

This may be a UK problem, Apple pay was launched in the UK today and it coincided with an update to ios8.4.

But I still have Passbook.. Is there a way of turning on wallet or has it simply not been launched in the UK yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Wallet app** is coming with `iOS 9`, and is not yet supported in `iOS 8.4`.

I've tested iOS 9 in Germany, and it will be supported in every country. They 'just' changed the name (and introduce a collective place for Apple Pay in the future).

[Source](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios9-preview/)

Comment: So will I be able to use Apple pay on 8.4 (maybe through passbook)? or will I have to upgrade to the ios9 beta to use apple pay?

Comment: Well, Apple Pay is depending on your country. Since it's not supported in Germany yet I have no idea how this will work. But you can use Apple Pay with Passbook, of course. I think you can store your MasterCard etc. there.

Comment: The Region setting is the one that enables/disabled the Credit Card part of Passbook (Wallet in iOS9) - so if you are in eg. Germany, you can change the Region to eg. US, and you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Pay will be launched in the UK "in July" and has not yet been released.
The Passbook app becomes Wallet with the release of iOS9 in the autumn.

Answer (score 0):

'Wallet' is an ios9 feature. It will be available in the fall